# Additional details in address field of Google Contacts to be ignored by Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, google-contacts

I need to have additional details in the address fields of my Google Contacts. These additional details interfere with Google Maps finding the address.

For instance: `Street Street Name 24, etaj 2, apartament 21, interfon 21C`. To find this address in Google Maps only `Street Street Name 24` is needed. Any other detail and will make the address not found. Is there a way to make these details ignored in Google Maps?

I have tried to separate them with a dash, a semicolon, a dot. I tried to enclose them in parenthesis, angle brackets. Nothing works.

These details are very important and must be linked to an address field in Contacts.